# Taking the Mean of Column of a Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Consider a random matrix A. I am trying to add a row to the bottom of A that consists of the mean of each column of A, calling the new matrix B.

Conisder `A=[1 2; 3 4];`

Then `B=[A(1,1:2) mean(A(:,1)) ; A(2,1:2) mean(A(:,2))];`

But this does not yield what I would expect.

Comment: @beaker I have found through trial and error that the solution is B= [A;mean(A,1)]. To me, this seems very counterintuitive. If we want to find the mean of the columns, shouldn't it be B= [A;mean(A,2)] (m by n matrix and not n by m)?

Comment: (Okay, your title and question contradict each other.) The first dimension in MATLAB is columnwise. `mean(A,1)` is equivalent to `[mean(A(:,1), mean(A(:,2)]` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do

```
B = [A ; mean(A,1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to concatenate the column means to the bottom of `A`

```
A = vertcat(A,mean(A))
```

or

```
A = [A;mean(A)]
```